# Iframe width and Height values

Tags: css, iframe, height, fixed-width

I have copy the code directly from the Site about my iframe which placed directly to my code.However when created a class *iframe* seems it doesn't read the values from the Class created on CSS but it bring its own size from the code that was bring with it along when i paste it directly to my code.
How can i re-size my Iframe so that it  can ready directly from the class(CSS)..I have deleted and remove the Height and width and set the size from its class it does not do the changes

This is my iframe code

```
      <div class="iframe">

            <iframe src="https://sway.com/s/3HuzZFFkT18WUe4M/embed" width="100%" marginwidth="0" height="100px" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" class="iframee" style="border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen
mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>

  </div>
```

my CSS - This width and height have no effects to the code

```
.iframe {
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    }
```

Comment: I chanced upon your question today. What caught my eyes was the fact that you were using a sway.com site inside an iframe, which is what I am trying now as well. I wonder if your page is still working since it seems as of now sway.com server is setting X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN and hence the iframe displays nothing.

Comment: you can use mozila fireforce inspector to copy it easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making style changes to the outer div using css class, but the styles to the iframe tag remains the same. You can put css on iframe tag like :

```
    iframe
    {
        max-height: 200vh;
        height:200px;
    }
```